Java image not displaying in 2D animation
I am following a tutorial where I have to make a Java 2D animation game. However, when I enter the exact same code as the person making the tutorial, he is getting the image displayed, and I am not, even though I have saved the image inside my working folder, and in the desktop as well. Can somebody please help me to understand why is the image not displaying. Thank you.
package animation2D;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    
    final int PANEL_WIDTH = 500;
    final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 500;
    Image enemy;
    Image backgroundImage;
    Timer timer;
    int xVelocity = 2;
    int yVelocity = 2;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    
    MyPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        enemy = new ImageIcon("enemy.png").getImage();
        backgroundImage = new ImageIcon("earth.jpg").getImage();
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paint(g); //Paint the background
        
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2D.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        g2D.drawImage(enemy, x, y, null);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x>=PANEL_WIDTH-enemy.getWidth(null) || x<0) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity * -1;
        }
        x = x + xVelocity;
        repaint();
        if (y>=PANEL_HEIGHT-enemy.getHeight(null) || y<0) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity * -1;
        }
        y = y + yVelocity;
        repaint();
    }
}

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHNWIWxRDDA

your problem is most likely related to the image name you are passing in as a parameter, you should use a path relative to where your application is running. So if you are running your application inside (example) ~/users/me/myapp and your image is in the desktop, you have to use new ImageIcon("~/users/me/Desktop/enemy.png")

Better to load your files/images as resources:
Netbeans
Eclipse
Also you should be overriding paintComponent

@JorgeCampos note that ~/.... is not a relative path, ~ hides the fact that you're actually specifying an absolute path rooted in the current user's home dir. The relative path in your example would be ../Desktop/enemy.png.

Hello Zubair, change new ImageIcon( "enemy.png" ).getImage(); to new ImageIcon( "/enemy.png" ).getImage();, (if your image is in the work directory).

Better still, load your images using ImageIO. Creating a component and discarding it in order to load an image is messy and inefficient. And once again, load the images as resources. If you want someone else to be able to run your hard work, you want to be giving them a jar file, not your computer

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeap, you are correct. I should not have used "relative" based on my example!

You should try to debug your code to see if the images are actually loaded - and verify that this is your actual problem. Then search again how to solve the problem you found - and if you can't get any further, update your question with your new insights.

I have tried adding / before the image name, as the image is stored in the working project, but its still not showing.

I have tried adding ... / ... That's not going to help one bit. / means "the file system root". What you need to know is the current directory, but as I said before, loading as images in a file system won't help you in the long run

It is mentioned in the video at 15 minute and 15 second mark (approximately), namely this is within my project folder (referring to file "space.png"). If you look at the image of the Eclipse IDE, you will see that files "space.png" and "enemy.png" are directly under "GUI Swing" which is the name of the [Java] project. Hence you need to do the same, i.e. make sure that your PNG (and JPG) files are located directly under the [Java] project.
When you run the code, the project folder is the working directory and the code you use to load that file will look for that file in the working directory.
Unfortunately, if the ImageIcon constructor does not find the file (because it is not in the working directory) it does not give any indication that it could not find the file, hence you have no idea that the file was not found and you don't understand why the image is not displayed.
There are alternative ways of creating an image that do throw an exception if the file is not found.
Personally, I think that videos are a poor way of learning Java. Of the few videos I have watched (including the one you linked to) they only explain the bare minimum and leave many holes and if you're not paying attention, you can miss something very important like: this is within my project folder. As a result you don't understand why your image is not displayed and you turn to SO for help.
Also, videos contain bad programming practices. Although the code works, it is recommended to override method paintComponent and not method paint.
Also, I don't see a date on the video so it may be very old and there may be new and better ways to achieve the same thing.
For learning Java, I recommend Oracle's Java tutorials. There is also a tutorial on Swing.
So to summarize the solution to your problem: Ensure that files "earth.jpg" and "enemy.png" are in the [Java] project folder of your IDE.
Note that the default working directory is the [Java] project folder, however in Eclipse IDE, you can change that via the run configuration. It doesn't matter what the working directory is, you just need to make sure that the image files are located in that directory when you run your code.

Its still not working. I have tried all the suggested methods, but its not showing.

@DanishZubair add the following three lines of code at the start of MyPanel constructor: System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); File f = new File("enemy.png"); System.out.println(f.isFile()); The first line will display the path to the working directory. The third line will display "true" if file enemy.png is located in the folder displayed by the first line. This is referred to as debugging.

if you want to load your image or file in the resources folder, you might need to use BufferedImage and ImageIO :
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO ;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D ;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage ;
import java.awt.Dimension ;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoadImage extends JFrame {
    public LoadImage() {
        super("Title") ;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
        
        add(new Panel()) ;
        // use this idea if you want to have exact window location
        pack() ;
        setLocationRelativeTo(null) ; // makes it center
    }
    
    // If you want to run the image in your panel
    public static class Panel extends JPanel {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage ;
        ImageIcon imageIcon ;
        Image image ;
        public Panel() {
            setLayout(null) ;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600)) ;
            
            // for loading your resources inside of you program, for example: src/main/resources/path/to/your/location.png
            try {
                bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/location.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace() ;
            }
            
            // for loading your image outside the program, for example: saves/image.png
            // if you create your jar, you need to put your files outside the jar
            image = new ImageIcon("path/to/your/location.png").getImage() ;
            imageIcon = new ImageIcon("path/to/your/location.png") ;
        }
        
        @Override 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g ;
            super.paintComponent(g) ;
            // for buffered image 
            if (bufferedImage != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null) ;
                g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null) ;
            }
            //for image icon 
            if (imageIcon != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null) ;
                g.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null) ;
            }
            // for image 
            if (image != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null) ;
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null) ;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // makes it write all the codes, then shows the code
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new LoadImage().setVisible(true)) ;
    }
}

hope this solution help you :)
i created a library that can handle your images, wav musics, files, creating or loading saves from various locations, user home, program directory check the link if you want JStreamLoader library on GitHub

// if you create your jar, you need to put your files outside the jar But that's a weakness, as is the fact that currently the image size bears no relation to the size of the custom component, which is arbitrary
